# Confusion in inserting a whole 200 records in dataTable into a database file in my code

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am a beginner in ADO.NET C# programming. My intent is to transform all records from dt (my DataTable) to a database file in Driver C (C:\datamining.mdf). However I am confused to do so, since I cannot use the known SQL Insert Statement {INSERT datatable VALUES (,,,,) } since my datatable has got 200 records. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace TextToDataBase
{
publicpartialclassForm2 : Form

{
public Form2()
{
InitializeComponent();
}
DataTable dt;
DataTable dt2;
privatevoid button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string str;
SqlConnection myConn = newSqlConnection("Server=(local);Integrated security=SSPI;database=master");
str = "CREATE DATABASE datamining_fourth ON PRIMARY" +
"(NAME=dataming_dat, FILENAME='C:\\dataminingforth.mdf', SIZE=10MB,MAXSIZE=50MB,FILEGROWTH=10%)" +
"LOG ON (NAME=datamining_log, FILENAME='C:\\dataminingforth.ldf', SIZE=1MB,MAXSIZE=5MB,FILEGROWTH=10%)";
SqlCommand myCommand = newSqlCommand(str, myConn); 
SqlConnection tableConn = newSqlConnection ("Server=(local);Integrated security=SSPI;database=datamining");
string str2;
str2= "CREATE TABLE drugdata ("+
"[Age] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,"+
"[Sex] [bit] NOT NULL"+
"[BP] [int] NULL"+
"[Cholestrol] [int] NULL"+
"[NA] [int] NULL"+
"[K] [int] NULL"+
"[Drug] [string] NULL"; 
SqlCommand tablecmd = newSqlCommand(str2,tableConn);
try

{
myConn.Open();
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("پایگاه داده با موفقیت ایجاد شد!", "پیغام", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
tableConn.Open();
tablecmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "خطا", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
finally

{
if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
myConn.Close();
if (tableConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
tableConn.Close();
}
}
privatevoid Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
dt = newDataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Age");
dt.Columns.Add("Sex");
dt.Columns.Add("BP");
dt.Columns.Add("Cholestrol");
dt.Columns.Add("Na");
dt.Columns.Add("K");
dt.Columns.Add("Drug");
StreamReader fg = newStreamReader("c:\\drug data mining.txt");
while (!fg.EndOfStream)
{
string val = fg.ReadLine();
string[] cells = val.Split(',');
for (int j = 0; j < cells.Length - 6; j++)
dt.Rows.Add(cells[0], cells[1], cells[2], cells[3], cells[4], cells[5], cells[6]);
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
dt2 = dt.Copy();
}
privatevoid button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

SqlConnection tableConn = newSqlConnection("Server=(local);Integrated security=SSPI;database=datamining");
string str2;
str2 = "CREATE TABLE drugdata (" +
"[Age] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL," +
"[Sex] [nvarchar] (50) NOT NULL," +
"[BP] [int] NULL," +
"[Cholestrol] [int] NULL," +
"[NA] [int] NULL," +
"[K] [int] NULL," +
"[Drug] [nvarchar] (50) NULL)";
SqlCommand tablecmd = newSqlCommand(str2, tableConn);
try

{
tableConn.Open();
tablecmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("جدول با موفقیت ایجاد شد!","پیغام", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "خطا", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
finally

{
if (tableConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
tableConn.Close();
}
}
privatevoid button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DataSet miningSet = newDataSet();
miningSet.Tables.Add(dt);
SqlConnection insrConn = newSqlConnection("Server=(local);Integrated security=SSPI;database=datamining");
SqlDataAdapter sda = newSqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM dt", insrConn);
sda.Fill(miningSet.Tables["dt"]);
/*


*/
try

{
insrConn.Open();
insrcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("عمل درج با موفقیت ایجاد شد!", "پیغام", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "خطا", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
finally

{
if (insrConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
insrConn.Close();
}
}
}
}
```

There is a space filled with `*/    /*` which needs to do the mentioned insertion. How could I do such operation? Could you please at least guide me with pseudocode?

Comment: Format your code properly first.

Comment: You have to much badly formated code and most of it is not needed to solve problem. People will ignore questions like this. Try to be short and keep only important parts of code.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are interested in loading data to dataset and saving changes back to database? Here is example where you edit data in dataSet and save changes.

```
    dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, databaseConnectionString);
    SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
    builder.GetUpdateCommand();
    dataSet = new DataSet();
    DataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
    //now you edit dataSet
```

SqlCommandBuilder should be used if you want to update changes made in dataSet back to SqlDatabase! Than you can write:

```
    dataAdapter.Update(dataSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to deal with DataAdapter (which is the better way), try something like this:

```
string insertStatement;
foreach (DataRow dRow in dt.Rows)
{
     insertStatement = "INSERT datatable VALUES (";
     foreach (object objItem in dRow.ItemArray)
     {
         insertStatement += objItem.ToString() + ",";
     }
     insertStatement = insertStatement.Substring(0, insertStatement.LastIndexOf(','));
     insertStatement += ")";
     // Than execute the insert statement
}
```